# Can a Kendo UI Pie chart tooltip contain the series category name?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui

I'm building a Kendo Chart in a razor view and have

```
 .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip.Visible(true))
```

Is there any other function on the configuration action that I can use to include the series category title on the tooltip?

The documentation for `Template()` and `Format()` appear to be for JS implementations rather than razor implementations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add in a specific template and format like so:

```
.Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip
    .Template("#=category# - #=value #")
    .Format("{0}%")
    .Visible(true)
)
```

This would give you a tooltip that looks like:

> Hydro - 22%

I believe that using the Template and Format helpers together may cause some conflict, but you can add a format into the template like this:

```
.Template("#=category# - #=kendo.format('{0}', value)#")
```

Comment: Perfect. Is there any documentation for how to use `.Template()` online?

Comment: You can check the kendo demos at http://demos.kendoui.com/dataviz/pie-charts/index.html, they have code examples in javascript, aspx and razor. Unfortunately they don't cover all examples so you might be left wanting; I don't think there is a documentation site specifically for MVC, but you may be able to translate the javascript once you get the hang of the way that the MVC helpers work.

Comment: if I want to use title text in template then?

Answer (score 3):

**[Templates](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dataviz/chart/tooltip#templates)**

Tooltip content can be defined with a Kendo Template when more flexibility is desired. The template provides access to all information associated with the point:

- value - the point value. Value dimensions are available as
  properties, for example, value.x and value.y
- category - the category
  name.
- series - the data series.
- dataItem - the original data item (when binding to dataSource).

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
.Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip
.Visible(true)
.Template("#= series.name #: #=kendo.format('{0:N0}', value)#")
)
```

For example, it shows the tooltip:

```
MySerie : 1.234.567
```

If only use:

```
.Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip
.Visible(true)
.Format("{0:N0}")
.Template("#= series.name #: #= value #")
)
```

It shows:

```
MySerie : 1234567
```